# Transform List<T> into another List<Pair<L,R>>

Tags: java, list

What is the best approach to transform a List into another List (e.g. in form `List<T> into another List<Pair<L,R>>`)  as shown in the diagram:

[image]

As shown, there is a source List which is `List<UserModel>` which essentially contains a `UserModel` with `getUserId()` method, this list can either be empty, contains one or more elements), so it is arbitrary. The goal is to create another List, in which it will contain a pair of String User ID's.

Here's a code to outline the problem;

```
List<UserModel> models= getUsers(); 
List<UserRenderModel> renderModels = new LinkedList<>();

        IntStream.range(0, models)
                .forEach(idx -> {
                            UserRenderModel renderModel = new UserRenderModel();
                            UserModel dataModel = models.get(idx);
                            if(idx % 2 == 0) {
                             renderModel.setLeftUserId(dataModel.getUserId());
                            } else {
                             renderModel.setRightUserId(dataModel.getUserId());
                            }
                            renderModels.add(renderModel);
                        }
                );
```

In this code you can see that if we have a `UserModel` with two objects in the collection it will create two `UserRenderModel` that will be added to the renderModels collection which is wrong, whereas it should just be one `UserRenderModel`

Comment: The usual approach would be `List#stream`, `Stream#map`, and finally `Stream#collect` using `Collectors#toList`.

Comment: What's the relationship between the `UserModel`s and the `UserRenderModel`s? Is it 1-to-1, by pairs, sliding window, or some other method?

Comment: Question updated @PatrickHaugh

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide too many details about the `UserModel` and `UserRenderModel` classes, but let's assume you have some way of transforming one to another:

```
private static UserRednerModel toRenderModel(UserModel u) {
    // pseudocode, of course:
    String leftUserId = getLeftIdFromId(u.getId());
    String RIGHTUserId = getRightIdFromId(u.getId());

    return new UserRenderModel(leftUserId, rightUserId);
}
```

Given such a method, I'd stream the list of `UserModel`s, map each one to a `UserRenderModel` and collect the to a new list:

```
List<UserModel> myList = ...;
List<UserRenderModel> result = 
    myList.stream()
          .map(SomeClass::toRenderModel)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to do

```
IntStream.range(0, models.size())
            .filter(idx -> idx % 2 == 0)
            .forEach(idx -> {
                UserModel userModel1 = models.get(idx);
                UserModel userModel2 = idx + 1 < models.size() ? models.get(idx + 1) : null;
                UserRenderModel renderModel = new UserRenderModel();
                renderModel.setLeftUserId(userModel1.getUserId());
                renderModel.setRightUserId(userModel2.getUserId());
            });
```